# From Excel Embedded Object to Base64 String in XML

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have an Excel sheet that allows users to click on specific cells and attach/embed files. These files are typically .pdf and .jpg format. I've read the Busy Developers guide on how to read embedded files using Apache POI, however I don't think I'm actually reading the correct file because when I go to save file locally or encode then decode for testing, the file says corrupt and will not open.

Here is some code:

```
for (PackagePart pPart : workbook.getAllEmbedds()) {
    InputStream inputStream = pPart.getInputStream();
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();

    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);

    attachmentFile.setValue(encoded);

    JAXBElement<Base64Binary> item = ncObjectFactory.createBinaryBase64Object(attachmentFile);

    attachment.getBinaryObject().add(item);
    attachment.getBinaryFormatID().add(idType);
    attachment.getBinaryDescriptionText().add(attachmentTextType);
    attachmentsType.getAttachment().add(attachment);
```

The above code gets it into base64 for my XML. However when I go to decode this in a test script, I am unable to open the files because the error in Adobe says that the file is corrupt or not saved correctly.

I get oleObject1.bin, or oleObject2.bin, or, oleObject3.bin, etc as I iterate through getAllEmbedds(). I believe this is the binary version of my embedded files, so how do I convert them back to their original format so they can be opened locally or on another machine?

My overall goal is to place embedded objects into an XML as Base64BinaryObjects, send XML to another system so it can pull those files out for review. My current issue is that once the files are retrieved from the XML, they won't open because they are corrupt/damaged/not correct format.

**Update:** Looking deeper into the oleObject.bin files, I see that some sort of wrapper is added to the original file. So there are bytes (?) added to the front and end of the original file. When I go to open the file in Adobe, I get that the file is corrupt since it can't find %PDF within the first 1024 bytes. So, I guess my question leads to - how do I remove the wrapper and/or the bytes at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Try using the Apache Tika CLI App in `-z` mode to extract all the embedded resources out - does that give you valid files?

Comment: Thank you for the support. I will try out the Tika CLI app, however I need a java solution for my overall goal (embedded objects to base64 String). Extracting was just a test case to see if pPart.getInputStream() actually got me what I needed. Maybe there's something wrong with how I'm encoding. My test was just to validate that I could at least extract those embedded files into local copies.

Comment: Apache Tika uses Apache POI underneath, so it's all java. The Tika App is just simply by far the simplest way to get the embedded files out to the local filesystem for testing!

Comment: The Apache Tika CLI App worked, however it's giving me what I already know (oleObject1.bin, oleObject2.bin, oldObject3.bin, etc). My issue is that I don't know how to return these files back to their original format (.pdf, .jpg, .png). When I try, it says the file is corrupt or not saved correctly. I know exactly what file name and MIME type these are yet I can't get them converted back correctly

Comment: Once the Tika CLI has extracted them out, what does running the Tika CLI with `--detect` mode on the extracted files detect them as?

Comment: --detect shows that *.bin files are  application/x-tika-msoffice-embedded; format=comp_obj

Comment: If you ask Tika to extract again from those `.bin` files, do you then get your real files out?

Comment: Nothing happens when I try extracting from the .bin files. I think my issue is converting the .bin file back to original format. I need to figure out how to convert it from .bin to .pdf

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure this out for oleObject.bin files. The problem is that the *.bin file was adding an OLE header to the original file and when I tried to read the file via Adobe, I got an error. So I had to either remove the added header or figure out how to get content without the header. Here's what worked for me:

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(pPart.getInputStream());
TikaInputStream stream = null;
stream = TikaInputStream.get(fs.createDocumentInputStream("CONTENTS"));

bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: what is the CONTENTS in your sample code , did you extract the *.bin objects to a file?