# Extracting embedded word pad from Microsoft Word document (docx) using java

Tags: java, ms-office, binaryfiles, text-extraction, wordpad

I have a word document which has multiple OLE objects embedded into it(MS word,Excel,PowerPoint and Word Pad) MS word exposes all other files and images as they are but it exposes the word pad and charts as binary files. 
I want to know if there is any tool available with Java APIs to extract or if it is possible to write some custom code by myself to convert these files back to RTF.

Comment: Have you checked [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)?

Comment: yes , i have used apache tika which in turn uses the poi library, but the problem is that ms word itself exposes the word pad files as .bin files hence even with poi or tika it would be extracted as a .bin file , i need a solution to that problem

Comment: Try checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165523/from-excel-embedded-object-to-base64-string-in-xml)

Comment: that really helped, got me really close to the solution and shortened my research by at least 2 days, thanks!